# How to attach mysql values to radio button and make it checked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make a radio button checked for Male and Female(lets say for example) when the php file is loaded by fetching the data's from mysql.

for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M"/>Female
```

now lets say i have stored the relevant radio button value to database.

Can anybody tell me how to retrieve it and display it on the web page but it should be checked.

Advance thanks to all those who would like to reply for my question.

Comment: you have to add some sample of your code, things you have tried already.

Comment: you can add the attribute `checked` to the button marker that you want .

Answer (score 1):

```
$value=$row['gender']; //value from db

$checked1=($value=="M")?'checked':'';
$checked2=($value=="F")?'checked':'';
```

and in html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <?php echo $checked1; ?>/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <?php echo $checked2; ?>/>Female
```